# I always get the same 'Browserify: command not found' error when trying to bundle files with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, browserify

I have tried solutions from every other question about this, but I still get the same 'Browserify: command not found' error when trying to bundle files using browserify.
Here is my project called 'gamefinal':
[image]

My goal is to bundle the s1.js file with browserify.
I have browserify installed in my node_modules, even though I've tried every way of bundling files with browserify suggested by similar questions, I still get the same error.

My node_modules:
[image]
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?